# How do I fix "require is not defined" error with Webpack and Babel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, require

I keep getting error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` in browser even with **Webpack** and **Babel**. For some reason I never had to worry about this before. I'm not sure if this error is caused by updated packages or what. I set up a very simple test application for simplicity.
**package.json**

```
{
   "name": "require-test",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index.js",
   "engines": {
      "node": "16.16.0"
   },
   "scripts": {
      "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
   },
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.18.10",
      "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.10",
      "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
      "webpack": "^5.74.0",
      "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
   }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
   target: "node",
   mode: "production",
   output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      clean: true,
      filename: (pathData) => {
         return 'index.js'
      },
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
               loader: 'babel-loader',
               options: {
                  presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**src/index.js** (js file before build)

```
const path = require('path');

console.log(path);
```

**dist/index.js** (js file after build)

```
(()=>{var r,e={17:r=>{"use strict";r.exports=require("path")}},t={};r=function r(o){var s=t[o];if(void 0!==s)return s.exports;var p=t[o]={exports:{}};return e[o](p,p.exports,r),p.exports}(17),console.log(r)})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're a few things on your code needing changed. First of all, you can't `target` to build for `node` while you run that code on browser which is wrong. Secondly, `path` is designed and built to run on node server specifically, however, there's a fallback for path on browser though which is called [`path-browserify`](https://github.com/browserify/path-browserify). You can check its document to see how it works.

Anyway to sum up, you need to switch `target` as `web` in the end:

```js
module.exports = {
 target: "web",
 // ...
}
```